# Delivery of SMS from blocked contact

Tags: contacts, call-screening, sms-blocking, blackberry

I would appreciate if someone could please let me know about the following:

1. When I block SMS messages from a contact and then eventually unblock it, then will I see all the messages that have been sent to me during the time the contact was blocked?
2. When I block a contact for incoming SMS messages, will the contact be blocked for incoming calls as well?
3. How do I know if my SMS messages has been delivered and/or read by the recipient?

[My device is BlackBerry Priv (Android)].

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you can't see.
2. No, blocking messages is different from blocking calls.
3. After your message is delivered you 'll see a single tick

For more options use Private space, Handcent SMS apps.

Comment: Actually I did a test, and it appears that I can actually see the messages which were sent to me while a contact was blocked, once I unblock it.